# 400 Bad request when posting jQuery ajax in Safari only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari

I've suddenly stared getting a 400 Bad request error in Safari when I POST a form to jQuery AJAX. I think this is strange, because it's been working fine for 2-3 years, and it's still working in Firefox. I'm not sure where to start debugging, can somebody help me?

```
submitHandler: function()
{
var formElement = document.getElementById("frmBanner");
var bannerfil = new FormData(formElement);  
bannerfil.append("gruppe412", $('#gruppe412').val() );

 $.ajax(
 {
     type: "POST",
     url: "/modContent/ajax/banner-copy.php?a=frmBanner&type=45",
     data: bannerfil,
     dataType: "html",
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function(data) 
     {
        if( data.length > 10 )
            $("#content").html( data );
        else
          location.href="#modContent/ajax/" + data;

     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.statusText); }
});

return false;
},
// Do not change code below
errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
}
}
```

Comment: We need logs to help you!

Comment: @Izio, ok, I'll have to mess around on the server a bit. Just a sec, I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Chrome console apart from HTTP 400?

Comment: @Luca I just tested Chrome. When I post in Chrome i get the directory listing of modContent/ajax/ in return. No other errors no.

Comment: @Izio I can't find anything useful in the error logs on the server?

Comment: Hm, it seems like the server is redirecting the AJAX call to the directory listing... Can you GET "/modContent/ajax/banner-copy.php?a=frmBanner&type=45" by simply typing it into the URL bar?

Comment: @Luca yes I can. Nevermind the directory listing, it was because I've been trying som debugging. The problem only occurs in Safari. Firefox and Chrome is no problem.

Comment: I noticed the same behaviour in one of my applications today. I tried to debug the requests and found out that it seems to be related to the content-length header. If you copy the request Safari is making to curl and remove the content-length header, does it work for you too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interestingly, I found the same problems on one of my websites just a few hours after your post. I agree with you that this has to be a more recent problem, but I couldn't tell which version of Safari introduced the bug.

Here's what I figured out:
You construct your `FormData` object by passing the form to it, which *should* be perfectly fine. But it seems like Safari has a bug: **When you construct the FormData object by passing a form with an empty file input to it, the request breaks for some reason**.

Work-Around:
Instead of doing `var bannerfil = new FormData(formElement);` to initialize my `FormData`, I'm now initializing an empty FormData object and add the values manually. Before adding a file input, I check whether it actually has any files attached.

```
formData = new FormData();
var $form = $(this); // <- change this depending on your scope/usecase

// [type="file"] will be handled separately
$form.find('input[name][type!="file"], select[name], textarea[name]').each(function(i, e) {
    if ($(e).attr('type') == 'checkbox' || $(e).attr('type') == 'radio') {
      if ($(e).is(':checked')) {
        formData.append($(e).attr('name'), $(e).val());
      }
    } else {
      formData.append($(e).attr('name'), $(e).val());
    }
});

$form.find('input[name][type="file"]').each(function(i, e) {
    if ($(e)[0].files.length > 0) {
      formData.append($(e).attr('name'), $(e)[0].files[0]); 
    }
});
```

Edit for clarification: In your specific case, something like this should make it work:

```
submitHandler: function() {
  var formElement = $("frmBanner");
  var bannerfil = new FormData();  

  // [type="file"] will be handled separately
  formElement.find('input[name][type!="file"], select[name], textarea[name]').each(function(i, e) {
    if ($(e).attr('type') == 'checkbox' || $(e).attr('type') == 'radio') {
      if ($(e).is(':checked')) {
        bannerfil.append($(e).attr('name'), $(e).val());
      }
    } else {
      bannerfil.append($(e).attr('name'), $(e).val());
    }
  });

  formElement.find('input[name][type="file"]').each(function(i, e) {
    if ($(e)[0].files.length > 0) {
      bannerfil.append($(e).attr('name'), $(e)[0].files[0]); 
    }
  });

  bannerfil.append("gruppe412", $('#gruppe412').val() );

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/modContent/ajax/banner-copy.php?a=frmBanner&type=45",
      data: bannerfil,
      dataType: "html",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data) {
          if( data.length > 10 )
              $("#content").html( data );
          else
            location.href="#modContent/ajax/" + data;

      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
          alert(xhr.statusText); 
      }
  });

  return false;
},
// Do not change code below
errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
  error.insertAfter(element.parent());
}
```

Comment: Nice, sorry for the late reply, I'll definitely test this and see if it works. It feels a bit like an unnecessary workaround, but it that what it takes to make it work so be it.

Comment: Well, if it's a bug in Safari there is not much we can do but to try and work around it. The fact that it works in every other browser and it even *used* to work in Safari definitely indicates it's a bug to me.

Comment: Hmm, if I run the above code (change formData to bannerfil), then I don't get any values from the form I'm posting...?

Comment: I just run it on the website where I use the other code. Replaced `var bannerfil = new FormData(formElement);` with your code to see if I could get it to work.

Comment: Depending on the scope you might need to replace `$(this)` with `$('#frmBanner')`.

Comment: I updated the answer with a code snippet that should work in your example.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer, it helped me out! but instead of iterate through all inputs, i decided to check only files. Remove files from formdata and then append only not empty files back again:

```
let formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
let files = formdata.getAll('upload[]');
formdata.delete('upload[]');
files.forEach(function(fileobject){
    if(fileobject.size){
        formdata.append('upload[]', fileobject);
    }
});
```